# How do you compare two ECU maps

Tags: motorcycle, electronic-control-module, triumph, tiger

I want to update my ECU mapping on my motorcycle to the latest one supplied by the manufacturer, but I'd also like to see what changed before doing so. I downloaded what was on the bike ECU and also got the latest release from the TuneECU website. I opened both with TuneECU individually and also in compare mode, but I can't see any difference, yet they have different versions in the meta-information and different file sizes. I'm not experienced with the TuneECU software, so it's also possible I'm using it wrong.

The F1 Table in both of them looks like this:
[image]

Can anyone please explain how to read a map and which of the tables are used when? And is there any difference between the two maps?

- On board - map version 20630
- Latest - map version 20654

Vehicle: Triumph Tiger 800, standard exhaust, no ABS

[Latest Triumph Maps.](http://www.tuneecu.com/Tune_List.html)

I also put both the maps I'm trying to compare in Dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0pmhwz4c0a6vhe/Tiger-OnBoard-Map-20630Map.hex?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg9yr6pyiz9p7ja/20654Map.hex?dl=0

Comment: Did you have a read [on the TuneECU website](http://www.tuneecu.com/TuneECU_En/mapedit.html)?

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes. I'm doing the F6 to compare and don't see any difference between the maps. I took another map (for the Arrow silencer) and for that one I see lots of differences. Or are you referring to something else that I may have missed? I'm starting to believe Triumph just bumped the version number and didn't change anything on the map.

Comment: they could have very well done that. :)

Comment: @AlinPurcaru  Good question.  I wish I had the answer.  I tried the dropbox links but nothing came up.

Comment: @DucatiKiller Nothing came up as in you couldn't download the maps, or you downloaded them and you didn't see the any differences.

Comment: I couldn't download them.

Comment: The files are publicly shared. I checked on a clean browser without being logged in. [chat]?

Comment: you could try asking Phil, at Youles Motorcycles, he's a Triumph lifer, he owns & micro manages a couple of Triumph dealerships, Winter is a quiet time for them, or phone them and ask a techi if one has a moment to spare. the guys in the workshop usually have all the workshop diary jobs under control by late afternoon, so that's probably the best time to ask a question of them. Phil is ok & not only the owner but a Triumph enthusiast an a fair mechanic. also very keen on acquiring good google reviews lol

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that there's no difference to the calibration itself. It depends on the manufacturer, but you'll commonly see revisions that are simply an operating system or process change, where the logic that interprets the tables gets tweaked, but the actual calibration data remains the same. If you look at the actual MAP file in hexadecimal, and the area your tables are stored in didn't change, but there's a whole bunch of stuff at the start of the file that's different, that's probably what's happening.

As far as how to read the map and which one is used when, that will also vary depending on what it is. Ford ECU's have something like 16 sets of tables they'll blend across. In general, whether the engine is

- MAF or Speed Density based (does it use a MAF sensor for airflow, or does it use a Volumetric Efficiency/ VE table to measure airflow)
- Running in Open Loop vs Closed Loop (is it using feedback from the oxygen sensors)

..Alters which tables you want to look at, because they determine whether the ECU is just going to run based off of a sensor (more or less), or if they're going to use your table directly. Some tables like ignition timing are obviously critical and are used all of the time.